# Error when add admin.py to the django app

Tags: django, django-admin

I haven't dealt with Django for some time and now when I returned to it, django 1.4 was released. I think my issue related to new release because earlier I haven't had such problem.

I have created project with myapp and also added easy-news app and everything worked fine, including admin site. But when I decided to add another app which needed admin.py. I've got an issue. When I add admin.py to my project I receive an error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/

'module' object has no attribute 'site'
```

for this string:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I have spent half a day trying to solve it but I don't understand where it comes from. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please show the full urls.py.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, and it showed up only with Django 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `admin.autodiscover()` to the project's urlconf?

This:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

must also be in the project's urlconf, and not in the app's.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes `admin.autodiscover()` is included and `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` in the project's urlconf.
As I've said until I add admin.py everything works. Don't know where to look.